# Eclipse PDT doesn't work on windows 7, when I run it, it displays the Eclipse Logo popup for a brief second and then disapears and crashes

Tags: crash, eclipse-pdt

I used Eclipse PDT for a while now on my Windows 7 and was working fine, but couple of months ago it stopped working for some reason. When I run it, it displays the Eclipse Logo popup for a brief second and then crashes and disapears. What can cause this and how to mend it? I tried deleting it, and re-unzipping, no use - same happens. I tried deleting just the workspace, no use - same happens. I tried deleting .eclipse in my user directory, doesn't work either.

Comment: I have solved this by uninstall Java completely (JRE and JDK - whatever you have on your computer). Uninstall all Java and reinstall it. Start Eclipse again. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vladimir Despotovic found the solution:

> I have solved this by uninstall Java completely (JRE and JDK -
>   whatever you have on your computer). Uninstall all Java and reinstall
>   it. Start Eclipse again. This solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

That can happen if you have corrupted your workspace files somehow. Remove the workspace folder temporary and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I will try it, but it doesn't even  get to choosing the workspace. Crashes before that even.

Comment: Do you get any kind of error number or something...?

Comment: I have solved this by uninstall Java completely (JRE and JDK - whatever you have on your computer). Uninstall all Java and reinstall it. Start Eclipse again. This solved it for me.

Comment: Dimitar, I can't make an answer due to my low rep, but you can do it and I can accept your answer in form of the answer there. I want to give you a thumbs up for the answer, since I already gave you the bounty before, in order to close this question. Thanks.